# why? error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database

Tags: database, android-room, converters

I stuck with a fool issue
I have response from server

```
 data class AddressResponse(
    @SerializedName("message") val responseMessage: String,
    @SerializedName("success") val success: Int,
    @SerializedName("status") val status: Int,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: Data
) {
  data class Data(
    @SerializedName("id") val addressId: Long,
    @SerializedName("status") val status: Int?,
    @TypeConverters( CommunicationPropertiesConverter::class )
    @SerializedName("communication_properties") val communicationProperties: AddAddressRequest.CommunicationProperties?,   
    @SerializedName("more_information") val moreInformation: String?                                           
  ) {
    data class CommunicationProperties(
      @SerializedName("par1") var par1: Boolean,
      @SerializedName("par2") val par2: Boolean,
      @SerializedName("par3") val par3: Boolean,
      @SerializedName("par4") val par4: Boolean
    )
  }
}
```

I use room and I have entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "db_address")
    data class DbAddress(
      @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_ID) val id: Long,
      @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_STATUS) val status: Int?,
      @TypeConverters(CommunicationPropertiesConverter::class)
      @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_COMM_PROPS) val communicationProperties: AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties,
      @ColumnInfo(name = COLUMN_MORE_INFO) val moreInfo: String?
    )
```

I have a convertor a set annotations @TypeConverters & @TypeConverter

```
    class CommunicationPropertiesConverter {
private val gson = Gson()

     @TypeConverter
      fun toCommunicationProperties(mString: String?): AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties {
        if (mString.isNullOrEmpty())
          return AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties(par1 = false, par2 = false, par3 = false, par4 = false)
        val listType = object : TypeToken<AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties>(){}.type
        return gson.fromJson(mString, listType)
    }

      @TypeConverter
      fun fromCommunicationProperties(properties: AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties?): String {
        if (properties == null)
          return "0000"
        return gson.toJson(properties)
    }
}
```

but I still get an error

> error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
> consider adding a type converter for it
> private final ... AddressResponse.Data.CommunicationProperties communicationProperties = null

but I added converter to and from "primitive" type

why? what did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and what worked for me was annotating that field (that has the custom type) with @Embedded. In my case, I didn't even need type converters anymore.